# Email Template in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have created a site for searching nearby restaurants and order items.

After ordering I wanna send a mail "Order received" with receipt attached in mail (if possible) to the customer + a mail to the respective restaurant which is in Craft->User "New Order" + a mail to site admin contains customer info and restaurants info + what I code in email template.

All these function will be done in single click. I mean when customer click on Order Now. These all mail will sent.

I am try to search email template and tutorial but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if anything in this help document needs clarifying: https://craftcommerce.com/support/sending-an-order-confirmation-email

Comment: @MohitPrajapati, could you please accept Luke's answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone coming to this for Craft 3 (super annoying that ALL the docs point to v2 still), the above link no longer works, and Craft has dropped all forms of example email templates which is a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need a plugin which listens for `commerce_orders.onOrderComplete`, fetches the restaurant in the order and sends the email to the restaurant owner. See https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onordercomplete